# RollingFileAppender - log4j, MaxBackUpIndex not taking into effect

Tags: apache, log4j, appender, rollingfileappender

Facing an issue where my log4j.properties file isn't allowing logs to roll over to a maximum of 10 log files using the MaxBackUpIndex. It currently only generates two files, one being a text file and the other being "file".

My config is:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${dd.apphome}/data/log/app.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %5p - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackUpIndex=8
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.Append=True
```

log4j version - 1.2.15

Any ideas on why this isn't rolling over and creating 8 files instead of 2? From my perspective everything looks to be configured OK.

Comment: Try changing the property `log4j.appender.file.MaxFileBackUpIndex` to `log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex`.

Comment: Same scenario I'm afraid, it generates two files, one being app.log and the other being app.log.1.

Answer (score 2):

Log4j file is case sensitive, it's MaxBackupIndex and not MaxBackUpIndex. Rookie error...

All working now.